# Group by one columns and find sum and max value for another in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Name  id  col1  col2  col3  cl4 
PL    252  0     747   3     53  
PL2   252  1     24    2     35 
PL3   252  4     75    24    13 
AD    889  53    24    0     95 
AD2   889  23    2     0     13  
AD3   889  0     24    3     6  
BG    024  12    89    53    66 
BG1   024  43    16    13    0   
BG2   024  5     32    101   4
```

And now I need to group by ID, and for columns col1 and col4 find the sum for each id and put that into a new column near to parent column (example: col3(sum)) But for col2 and col3 find max value. 
Desired output:

```
Name  id  col1 col1(sum) col2 col2(max) col3 col(max) col4 col4(sum)
PL    252  0       5      747    747     3     24    6    18
PL2   252  1       5      24     747     2     24    12   18
PL3   252  4       5      75     747     24    24    0    18
AD    889  53      76     24     24      95    95    23   33
AD2   889  23      76     2      24      13    95    5    33
AD3   889  0       76     24     24      6     95    5    33
BG    024  12      60     89     89      66    66    0    67   
BG1   024  43      60     16     89      0     66    63   67    
BG2   024  5       60     32     89      4     66    4    67
```

What is the easiest and fastest way to calculate this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use groupby/transform to creat the required columns

```
df[['col1_sum', 'col4_sum']]=df.groupby('id')['col1', 'cl4'].transform('sum')
df[['col2_max', 'col3_max']]=df.groupby('id')['col1', 'cl4'].transform('max')

    Name    id  col1    col2    col3    cl4 col1_sum    col4_sum    col2_max    col3_max
0   PL      252 0       747     3       53  5           101         4   53
1   PL2     252 1       24      2       35  5           101         4   53
2   PL3     252 4       75      24      13  5           101         4   53
3   AD      889 53      24      0       95  76          114         53  95
4   AD2     889 23      2       0       13  76          114         53  95
5   AD3     889 0       24      3       6   76          114         53  95
6   BG      24  12      89      53      66  60          70          43  66
7   BG1     24  43      16      13      0   60          70          43  66
8   BG2     24  5       32      101     4   60          70          43  66
```

Answer (score 29):

The most (pandas) native way to do this, is to use the [`.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) method that allows you to specify the aggregation function you want to apply per column (just like you would do in SQL).

Sample from the documentation:

```
df.groupby('A').agg({'B': ['min', 'max'], 'C': 'sum'})
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) when you have [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) on id :

```
pd.merge(df,df.groupby("id").sum().reset_index(), on='id',how='outer')
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I know this is messy but I like chaining so you can do something like this:

```
df = df.groupby('id').
    apply(lambda g: g.assign(
        col1_sum=g.col1.sum(),
        col2_max=g.col2.max()))
```

Basically, this is applying a group based assign command to each group and then combining into a single DataFrame.

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html for details on each method.